# Isomorphism Quotient Polynomial Rings 2 Var

Tags: polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

### Examine Whether:

$$
\frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{<x^2-y^2-1>} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}
[x,y]}{<xy -1>}
$$

### Background:

- 2nd year math undergrad
- Currently doing introductory ring theory

### What I Know\Questions:

- $ R[x,y] \cong R[x][y] \cong R[y][x]$
- $f(x,y) \in R[x,y],\space\space\space f_i \in R[x]$ 
  $f(x,y) = f_0(x) + f_1(x)y + f_2(x)y^2 + ...$
- Factorization concept of polynomial rings in 1 var doesnt translate for multiple variables
- $<xy-1>$ is additive identity 
  $xy-1 =0 \implies x=\frac{1}{y}$
- $\frac{R[x,y]}{<xy -1>} \cong R[x,1/x]$ 
  This is laurent series ,ie, power series 
  As far as i understand, $\forall x^n \space\space \space(x^n)^{-1} exists$

  Is this correct?
- For the above isomorphism, thus if one can show the left quotient ring doesnt have some of the properties of laurent series then its not isomorphic 
  Or if kernel is $<x^2-y^2-1>$ for $\phi : R[x,y] \rightarrow \frac{R[x,y]}{<xy -1>}$
  Then it is isomorphic

Evidently, either i haven't understood enough or am not able to justify  either to come to some conclusion.

Comment: use $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ and change the variables to $x+y$ and $x-y$

Comment: @user8268 So **u=(x+y)** & **v=(x-y)** effectively transforms to **R[u,v]/<uv -1>**. But i dont really know how to state the same formally for my exams, could you elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Is $R$ supposed to be a general ring or the reals?

Comment: Oh, right, in the question it was Real Numbers so effectively R is a field, but any ring with characteristic zero would do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Solution (case $R=\mathbb R$):}$

---

Let’s define the isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R[u,v]\to\mathbb R[x,y] $, such that $\phi(u)=x+y, \phi(v)=x-y, \phi(1)=1$ (it’s easy to construct the inverse). Now $x^2-y^2-1=(x-y)(x+y)-1=\phi(uv-1)$. Now the morphism $$\psi=\pi\circ\phi:\mathbb R[u,v]\to \mathbb R[x,y]\to\frac{\mathbb R[x,y]}{\langle x^2-y^2-1\rangle},$$
is surjective (because it’s the composition of two surjective homomorphism) and if $\psi(p(u,v))=0$ we have, for the injectivity of  $\phi$, that $\phi(p(u,v))=p(x+y,x-y)\in\langle x^2-y^2-1\rangle \implies p(x+y,x-y)=(x^2-y^2-1)q(x,y)=((x+y)(x-y)-1)q(x,y)$

now we just have to apply $\phi^{-1}$: $$p(u,v)=\phi^{-1}(p(x+y,x-y))=\phi^{-1}\bigg(((x+y)(x-y)-1)q(x,y)\bigg)=(uv-1)\phi^{-1}(q(u,v)) \implies p(u,v)\in \langle uv-1\rangle .$$ we just proved that $\langle uv-1\rangle\supset\ker\psi$ (the other inclusion its trivial, hence $\langle uv-1\rangle=\ker\psi$).

Now we have just to use the [Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) which guarantees the existence of isomorphism :$$\bar\psi:\frac{\mathbb R[u,v]}{\langle uv-1\rangle}\to\frac{\mathbb R[x,y]}{\langle x^2-y^2-1\rangle}$$ (the surjectivity follows from the surjectivity of $\psi$,  while the injectivity from $\langle uv-1\rangle=\ker\psi$ ).

$\textbf{Inverse of } \phi:$

---

It is immediate to verify that $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb R[x,y]\to\mathbb R[u,v]$
is such that $\phi^{-1}(x)=(u+v)/2,\;\phi^{-1}(y)=(u-v)/2$

$\textbf{if $R$ is a generic field? } $

---

The solution works even if $R\neq \mathbb R$, but we needed the inverse of 2 to construct the inverse of $\phi$. But if char($R$)=2 then there is no isomorphism:

In  $\frac{\mathbb R[x,y]}{\langle x^2-y^2-1\rangle}$ there is a non-trivial idempotent element $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy=x^2+y^2=x^2-y^2=1.$ However in $\frac{\mathbb R[x,y]}{\langle xy-1\rangle}$ every element has a unique writing in the form (using $xy=1$): $$a_0+\sum^n a_i x^i+\sum^m b_iy^i, \text{ with } a_i,b_i\in \mathbb F_2, $$ and there is no idempotent element because (wlog $n\ge m$ with $a_n\neq 1$): $$(a_0+\sum^n a_i x^i+\sum^m b_iy^i)^2=a_n^2x^{2n}+(\text{other terms with lower degree in $x$})\implies  (\ldots)^2\neq 1.$$ hence there is no non-trivial idempotent element.

Comment: Can you write down the *easy* inverse in the case $R=\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: I worked in the event that $R=\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Bongo i intuitively understand why phi is isomorphic (as in terms of linear algebra x+y & x-y are linearly independent), but i am failing to explicitly prove it here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer depends on whether $2\in R^\times$ or not.

Assume it is. Then as @user8268 suggested, it is a mere change of variables:
You have a map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\phi:R[s,t]/(st-1) &\rightarrow& R[x,y]/((x+y)(x-y)-1)\\
s&\mapsto&x+y\\
t&\mapsto&x-y
\end{array}$$
and at the same time a map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\psi:R[x,y]/((x+y)(x-y)-1) & \rightarrow & R[st]/(st-1)\\
x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(s+t)\\
y \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(s-t)
\end{array}$$
These maps are welldefined, since the universal property of $R[x,y]$ provides us with maps, which send everything in the respective ideals to zero. It is not hard to check that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are mutually inverse to each other.

**Note**: this specific isomorphism requires $\frac{1}{2} \in R$! This doesn't disprove another isomorphism lurking in the background.

I think $R=\mathbb{F}_2$ provides us with a counterexample. We want to show that there is no isomorphism
$$R[s,t]/(st-1) \cong R[x,y]/((x+y)^2-1).$$
A homomorphism $f:R[s,t]/(st-1)\rightarrow R[u]$ picks a unit $f(s)\in R[u]^\times=R^\times=\{1\}$ and its inverse $f(s)^{-1}=f(t)\in R^\times$. This shows that $\operatorname{Hom}(R[x,y]/(st-1),R[u])=\{*\}$. Meanwhile, a homomorphism $g:R[x,y]/((x+y)^2-1) \rightarrow R[u]$ picks elements $g(x),g(y)\in R[u]$, which satisfy the relation $(g(x)+g(y))^2=1$. There are alot of those, for example given by $g(x)=u^n, g(y)=u^n+1$ for $n\in \mathbb N$. But this shows $\operatorname{Hom}(R[x,y]/((x+y)^2-1),R[u]) \neq \{*\}$. But if the rings *were* isomorphic, these Hom-sets would have to be isomorphic...

Comment: By {*}, do you mean to imply that the only homorphism is the one where f(s) maps to 1 which is the only unit in F2, and what is the universal property of **R[x, y]**, i am not familiar with that

Comment: To the first question: yes exactly. To the second question: with universal property I mean the fact, that a ring homomorphism out of a polynomial ring $R[x,y]$ is determined by where it sends $x$ and where $y$. It is basically the same as saying that a linear map out of a vector space is determined by what it does on a basis...